# send_keys() giving error in python 3 selenium code with firefox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

baseurl = "https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=J5ooWerXOsf_8AebtKKICw&gws_rd=ssl"
search = "panda"

xpaths = { 'searchbox' : ".//*[@id='lst-ib']",
   'submit' : ".//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]",
   'img' : ".//*[@id='gbw']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a"
 }

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(baseurl)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['searchbox']).clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['searchbox']).send_keys(search)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submit']).click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['img']).click()
```

Firefox opens, but nothing at all happens, and written in the terminal is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sg1.py", line 21, in <module>
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['searchbox']).send_keys(search)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 347, in send_keys
self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
```

Things to note:
Firefox is up to date.

When Firefox opens it opens a plain version and not the version that usually opens with add-ons such as adblocker, firebug, etc.

When i ran just the click on 'img' bit that is commented out it did what it was supposed too.

Comment: update your geckodriver version to 0.16 also selenium to 3.4.0

Comment: Ok I will do both of those things as soon as I get back home.  If I have a concern or problem may I ask you for a point in the right direction if it needed?

Comment: yes of course...

Comment: Ok, I'm back home. It's been a while since I had to install geckodriver and I remember I had to do a lot of reading on putting it in the correct place and such. Do you know an easy was I could just update it to that version from terminal. And should I update selenium or geckodriver first?

Comment: No such restrictions are there

Comment: Ok,  so how can I update geckodriver right from terminal instead of having to download from a web link?

Comment: I don't know that there is a way to do so; you have to download it from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: I would like to inform you that your suggestions have solved my problem completely and it works as it's supposed too. Thanks you very much. If you would like then post your solution as the answer and I'll mark it as correct so that it can be of help to anyone else who may be experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Hey,  so would you like to post that as the answer or should I? Like I said I think it could be helpful for others with the same problem. .

Comment: I've posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is common with `geckodriver v.015`; In order to resolve this update your geckodriver version to 0.16 also `selenium` to 3.4.0.